# Change keyboard shortcut for {} and [] in German keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard

I'm new to Mac and using a Macbook Air with Lion and a German keyboard. From my PC I'm used to other keyboard shortcuts for {} and [].

Currently it's alt + 8,9 for {} and alt + 5,6 for []. Can I change this to the PC ones (cmd + 7,0 and cmd + 8,9)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to create these shortcuts with Spark: http://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele). It's a keyboard layout editor for Mac OS X.

Comment: Hm ... it's a little bit to complicated for me.

Comment: I'm just trying to help...