# Mac OS X, install another keyboard layout?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I'm a developer and I'm just so used to using Spanish (Argentina) as my keyboard layout on my PC both at home and at work. Now I want to develop on my Macbook Pro too, but the only Spanish layouts available are "regular" and ISO, both of which are basically the same as the one I use, except I have to press the alt key to input characters that are very common for me, like {}[].

How can I set my keyboard layout to Spanish (Argentina)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the Windows Latin American layout mentioned in this article meet your needs?

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2007/02/more-ways-to-type-spanish.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19490/change-keyboard-shortcut-for-and-in-german-keyboard-layout) to be helpful for your problem. The two tools referred to in the answers are [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele) and [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php).

Ukulele allows you to edit keyboard layouts (thus creating the layout you want), while Spark creates shortcut key combinations, which you could use to remap a few keys to create the layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

I created this project in github for Latin American keyboard in macOS, maybe it helps you. https://github.com/neosergio/Latam-Keyboard